Export SQL Server Agent Jobs from a drive
I have a bit of a pickle here. Our old server with SQL Server 2008 was malware infected and been shut down. We've restored the databases from backup into a new server. However, Agent Jobs have not been backed up in any way and turns out there were some important jobs there.
I've spoke to our infrastructure team and the best they can do is to mount the disk from that server, so I can browse files on that infected server. No way to start up that server safely.
Question: is there a way to extract any information about SQL Jobs by just browsing drive containing SQL Server installation?
p.s. I've seen all the instructions on how to extract and backup Agent Jobs, but all those instruction assume that SQL Server is up and running - I have no such luxury.


p.s. I've seen all the instructions on how to extract and backup Agent Jobs, but all those instruction assume that SQL Server is up and running - I have no such luxury.

You could setup a new instance of SQL Server on a different server and use the system databases from that drive, either directly by making the drive share accessible to the other server, or by copying the system database files (*.mdf and *.ldf) to that new server. Note SQL Agent Jobs are particularly stored in the msdb database.
Whichever your infrastructure team is more comfortable with. I'd leave it to them to decide what has the lowest risk, though I'd recommend that new server being disconnected from the rest of the network.
After you do that, you can script out the SQL Agent Jobs and copy the text of the scripts somewhere safe, so they may be later ran on the final new server where the Jobs need to be.

If you have backups of the databases then hopefully you also have backups of the system databases.
If you do, then restore the system databases before restoring the user databases and all your SQL Agent jobs (and logins, credentials, etc.) will be back as they were.
If you don't have system database backups then copying the .mdf and .ldf files as mentioned by @J.D. is the alternative.  And then remember to include the system databases in the backup strategy for the new server!

I'm afraid I'm not so lucky - no system DBs backups :-(
